# CUDA: Using cudaMemcpyHostToDevice with structs

Tags: c, cuda

I have:

```
typedef struct
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}vec3;
```

lineCuda.cu

```
extern "C" void cudaTranslate(vec3 *grid, float xrot,vec3 center, int multi)
{
    vec3 *dev_grid[2000];
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_grid, sizeof(vec3)*2000 ) ;
    cudaMemcpy(dev_grid, grid, sizeof(vec3)*2000, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); //error
```

Compiles fine but runtime shows: First-chance exception at 0x75c6b727 in cube.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cudaError_enum at memory location 0x002cbef8..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vec3 *dev_grid[2000];
```

should be

```
vec3 dev_grid[2000];
```

ok i see, make it

```
vec3 *dev_grid = 0;
```

[http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/2_3/toolkit/docs/online/group_*CUDART*_ERROR.html](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/2_3/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__ERROR.html)

> const char *   cudaGetErrorString (cudaError_t error)
>       Returns the message string from an error code.
>   cudaError_t    cudaGetLastError (void)
>       Returns the last error from a runtime call.

Comment: tried. same error: First-chance exception at 0x75c6b727 in cube.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cudaError_enum at memory location 0x00374d1c..

Comment: could you explain how to do such a thing? Thanks.

Comment: THANK YOU. Could you explain why?

Comment: nevermind. I understand now after going over it again. Thank you again!

Comment: @Nin, yeah you mixed up ** and * pointers which are subtly different when used with & operator

Answer (score 0):

CUDA uses a host pointer (on the CPU) to point at a block of device memory (on the GPU).

To do this, it modified the pointer on the cudaMalloc call. Later, the memory on the GPU is freed with a corresponding cudaFree call.

When you allocate dev_grid, you allocated using the CPU. Modification of the pointer would have made it impossible for the CPU to free the memory later using free, delete, or other similar mechanism. Thus, CUDA most likely has a check built-in to prevent this from happening, making cudaMalloc only work on currently null pointers.